# Trouble generating a table from a Do function

Tags: output-formatting

Basically i have this function that computes several partial derivatives for every value of alpha, beta, and gamma as it sums delta from 1 to 4. It gives an output for every value straight down the page, but i can't get it into a table form. Whenever i try it may come up with a list that contains "{Null}" in every place. I'll put the line without the attempts at a table below. Basically it picks pieces from a matrix and performs partial derivatives with respect to a coordinate chosen from a list called "coord".

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
list1 = {1 - (2 m)/r, -(1/(1 - (2 m)/r)), -r^2, -r^2*Sin[θ]^2}
Metric = DiagonalMatrix[list1]
InverseMetric = Inverse[Metric]
coord = {t, r, θ, ϕ};
Do[
  Print[
    Sum[(1/2) * InverseMetric[[α, δ]] *
      (D[Metric[[γ, δ]], coord[[β]]] + 
       D[Metric[[β, δ]], coord[[γ]]] - 
       D[Metric[[β, γ]], coord[[δ]]]), 
      {δ, 1, 4, 1}]], 
  {α, 1, 4, 1}, {β, 1, 4, 1}, {γ, 1, 4, 1}]
```

Comment: Hi there. You have not defined the metric and its inverse. Maybe this fixes the problem?

Comment: I've added them for context

Comment: You get a 4 by 4 by 4 matrix. Just replace the `Do` by `Table` and remove the `Print`

Comment: `Table[Sum[(1/2)*
    InverseMetric[[\[Alpha], \[Delta]]]*(D[
       Metric[[\[Gamma], \[Delta]]], coord[[\[Beta]]]] + 
      D[Metric[[\[Beta], \[Delta]]], coord[[\[Gamma]]]] - 
      D[Metric[[\[Beta], \[Gamma]]], coord[[\[Delta]]]]), {\[Delta], 
    1, 4, 1}], {\[Alpha], 1, 4, 1}, {\[Beta], 1, 4, 1}, {\[Gamma], 1, 
   4, 1}] // Simplify`

Comment: Thanks Nasser and Bob, i forgot to remove the print. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results as a table, then use `Table`, not `Do`. Like so.

```
list1 = {1 - (2 m)/r, -(1/(1 - (2 m)/r)), -r^2, -r^2*Sin[θ]^2};
Metric = DiagonalMatrix[list1];
InverseMetric = Inverse[Metric];
coord = {t, r, θ, ϕ};

tbl = 
  Table[
    Sum[(1/2) InverseMetric[[α, δ]]
      (D[Metric[[γ, δ]], coord[[β]]] +
       D[Metric[[β, δ]], coord[[γ]]] -
       D[Metric[[β, γ]], coord[[δ]]]),
      {δ, 4}],
    {α, 4}, {β, 4}, {γ, 4}]
```

> ```
>  {{{0, m/((1 - (2 m)/r) r^2), 0, 0}, {m/((1 - (2 m)/r) r^2), 0, 0, 0}, 
>    {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, 
>   {{(m Csc[θ]^2 (-2 m r^3 Sin[θ]^2 + r^4 Sin[θ]^2))/r^6, 0, 0, 0}, 
>    {0, -((m Csc[θ]^2 (-2 m r^3 Sin[θ]^2 + r^4 Sin[θ]^2))/((1 - (2 m)/r)^2 r^6)), 0, 0}, 
>    {0, 0, -((Csc[θ]^2 (-2 m r^3 Sin[θ]^2 + r^4 Sin[θ]^2))/r^3), 0}, 
>    {0, 0, 0, -((-2 m r^3 Sin[θ]^2 + r^4 Sin[θ]^2)/r^3)}}, 
>   {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/r, 0}, {0, 1/r, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -Cos[θ] Sin[θ]}}, 
>   {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/r}, {0, 0, 0, Cot[θ]}, {0, 1/r, Cot[θ], 0}}}
> ```

If this 4 x 4 z 4 tensor doesn't have the shape you want, Mathematica has several tools to reshape it.